# Laravel querying Reserved room count

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

For a hotel booking system, i am getting total room count and reserved room count.

Available room count is : 5

A user is booked that room  From : 2018-02-22 To : 2018-02-24

But if user searches for date 25 and 26 the below count is giving zero. there must be problem in my `'<='` or `'>='` but i cant able to find.

```
$reservedCount = Reservation::where('check_in', '>=', $checkin_date)->where('check_out', '<=', $checkout_date)->count();

$reservedCount = Reservation::
                    whereBetween('check_in', [$checkin_date, $checkout_date])
                  ->whereBetween('check_out', [$checkin_date, $checkout_date])
                  ->count();
```

the above two queries also retuns zero where am i doing wrong?

`$checkin_date` and `$checkout_date` are user entered date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for (reservation) range overlaps, you should use:

```
$reservedCount = Reservation::where('check_in',  '<=', $checkout_date)
                            ->where('check_out', '>=', $checkin_date)
                            ->count();
```

Note that for hotel room reservations you would usually use `<` and `>` instead of `<=` and `>=`, because one customer can check in on the same day when another one checks out.

Note that something like

```
whereBetween('check_in', [$checkin_date, $checkout_date])
->orWhereBetween('check_out', [$checkin_date, $checkout_date])
```

will not find an overlap for

```
check_in  = 2018-02-10
check_out = 2018-02-20
$checkin_date  = 2018-02-12
$checkout_date = 2018-02-18
```

because neither `2018-02-10` nor `2018-02-20` are between `2018-02-12` and `2018-02-18`.

Comment: i have previously accepted jerome's answer. but got bugs like `note` in this asnwer. so this one works with overlap also. after changing this `->where('check_out', '>', $checkin_date)`

Answer (score 6):

Can you try

```
$reservedCount = Reservation::
                whereBetween('check_in', [$checkin_date, $checkout_date])
              ->orWhereBetween('check_out', [$checkin_date, $checkout_date])
              ->count();
```

Comment: the second one works as expected. remove the first one.

Comment: if the replacement is better than this, then yes

Answer (score 0):

Can try

```
where(function ($query)
{
    $query->where('check_in' ,'>=', $checkin_date)
        ->orWhere('check_out', '<=', $checkout_date);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in where clause, to check between dates

```
    $filters=[$checkin_date,$checkout_date];

    $event->where(function ($query) use ($filters) {
      $query->whereBetween('check_in', $filters);
      $query->orWhereBetween('check_out', $filters);
    });
```